# IntelliJ IDEA can not auto import

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using `IntelliJ 2016.1.2`.

When I create a `java.sql.Timestamp` and enter `alt + enter` for auto import, my IntelliJ seems can not give me a hint about it. I have to import it mannully.

[image]

[image]

Other class in java.sql.* works fine.

[image]

How to sovle this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: probably because you try to instantiate it with a constructor that doesn't exist for java.sql.Timestamp. add a Long value as parameter

Comment: try adding an implementation of java.sql to your buildpath

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this has nothing to do with the IDE. just tried it with IntelliJ, it finds the class just fine.

Comment: @user27149 try invalidating intellij caches and restarting intellij

Comment: @user27149 how have you configured your dependencies/version of java?

Comment: I've noticed in IntelliJ that even though Java 8 is configured, it still uses a different version (for example: to compile). I doubt this is the problem, but it can be part of it.

Comment: @user27149 in my IntelliJ, so does Timestamp, so I doubt the issue is the IDE itself, maybe a version of Java (run or compiletime) or the version used for a module/facet ... Does it work if you manually add the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the class is excluded from `Auto Import`

- open the `Settings Dialog` CTRL-ALT-S
- navigate to `Editor -> General -> Auto Import`
- on the right side there is a list `Exclude from Import and Completion` where